# Deleting tasks in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to learn Vue.js. First time making a small to-do app and I'm trying to delete each individual task on click, but nothing is happening. I've been watching a bunch of youtube tutorials to try to figure it out but no luck :( Any help appreciated!
I don't think I am passing through the `$emit` and the id correctly.

Also, if anyone has any helpful tutorials please let me know!

App.vue

```
<template>
  <Tasks :tasks="tasks" @delete-task="deleteTask" />
</template>

<script>
import Tasks from "./components/Tasks.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Tasks,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tasks: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    deleteTask(id) {
      this.tasks = this.tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== id);
    },
    addTask(newTask) {
      this.tasks = [...this.tasks, newTask];
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.tasks = [
      {
        id: 0,
        text: "Grocery shopping",
        date: "March 25, 2022",
        reminder: true,
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        text: "Doctors Appointment",
        date: "March 30, 2022",
        reminder: true,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        text: "Pay Bills",
        date: "April 1, 2022",
        reminder: false,
      },
    ];
  },
};
</script>
```

Tasks.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Task :tasks="tasks" @delete-task="$emit('delete-task')" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Task from "./Task.vue";

export default {
  name: "Tasks",
  emits: ["delete-task"],
  components: {
    Task,
  },
  props: {
    tasks: Array,
  },
};
</script>
```

Task.vue

```
<template>
  <div v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id" @click="onDelete(task.id)">
    <p>{{ task.text }}</p>
    <p>{{ task.date }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Task",
  emits: ["delete-task"],
  props: {
    tasks: Object,
  },
  methods: {
    onDelete(id) {
      this.$emit("delete-task", id);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: put a console.log in `deleteTask` ... does it run when you try to delete? In tasks.vue, try `@delete-task="id => deleteTask(id)"` - create a `deleteTask(id)` method, and have it console.log the id passed in - and also `this.$emit('delete-task', id)` - does that work?

Comment: `@delete-task="$emit('delete-task')"`... you're not emitting any payload, ie the task `id` is missing

Comment: I have tried ```@delete-task="$emit('delete-task', id)"``` in Tasks.vue but it doesn't work. When i try a console.log in deleteTask it does run....

Comment: try `@delete-task="id => $emit('delete-task', id)"`

Comment: `i try a console.log in deleteTask it does run` - and what does it output?

Comment: @Bravo  ```@delete-task="id => $emit('delete-task', id)"```  this worked! Thank you, i guess this makes sense as I have to pass the id

Comment: personally, I never `$emit` in a `@xxxx` - I always create a function and emit from that (like you do in Task.vue) - I find it's easier to debug that way (adding console.log's etc)

Answer (score 3):

Tsaks.vue no ID passed to App.vue component

```
<template>
 <div>
<Task :tasks="tasks" @delete-task="$emit('delete-task')" />
</div>
</template>
===>
<template>
 <div>
 <Task :tasks="tasks" @delete-task="(id)=>$emit('delete-task',id)" />
 </div>
</template>
```